# How to make Ubuntu 17 detect 2 graphic boards?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 17.10, multiple-monitors

I have Ubuntu 17, I want to display 4 different monitors without cloning them, each board has 2 outputs, so now i can use 2 monitors with just only one board, but i have 2 graphic boards connected.

```
root@albert:/home/albert# nvidia-smi -L
GPU 0: GeForce GT 220 (UUID: GPU-c972cace-40a8-4b9b-3a40-ff6831dcfe96)
GPU 1: GeForce GT 220 (UUID: GPU-fc6e9eb7-9f3c-a28b-e54b-ceedb2116b7f)
```

but the other 2 outputs of the another board doesnt appear in the monitor settings just is shown 2 monitors of the same board.

How to make ubuntu detect the other graphic board on monitor settings ?